# Can someone tell me whats wrong with my slugging percentage query?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to figure out why my total bases and slugging queries (they're built into a master query) are giving me inflated results. I've run each in a separate query and I've gotten numbers that are closer to what I want (but not correct). You will need some basic knowledge of baseball to help me!

```
Select 
      bbat.playerID, 
      bmast.firstname, 
      bmast.lastname, 
      bbat.yearID, 
      bbat.TeamID, 
      bmast.bats, 
      bmast.throws, 
      bfield.POS, 
      bbat.G, 
      bbat.G_batting, 
      bbat.AB, 
      bbat.R, 
      bbat.H, 
      bbat.2B, 
      bbat.3B, 
      bbat.HR, 
      bbat.RBI, 
      bbat.HBP, 
      bbat.SF, 
      (Sum(H)+(Sum(2B)*2)+(Sum(3B)*3)+(Sum(HR)*4)) as 'TB',
      bbat.BB, 
      bbat.SO, 
      (Sum(BB)/Sum(SO)) as 'BB/K', 
      (SUM(H)/Sum(AB)) as 'Avg',
      ((Sum(H)+Sum(BB)+Sum(HBP))/(Sum(AB)+Sum(BB)+Sum(HBP)+Sum(SF))) as 'OBP', 
      (Sum(H)+(Sum(2B)*2)+(Sum(3B)*3)+(Sum(HR)*4))/Sum(AB) as 'Slugging', 
      (((Sum(H)+Sum(BB)+Sum(HBP))/(Sum(AB)+Sum(BB)+Sum(HBP)+Sum(SF)))+((Sum(H)+(Sum(2B)*2)+(Sum(3B)*3)+(Sum(HR)*4))/Sum(AB))) as 'OPS',
      bbat.SB, 
      bbat.CS, 
      (Sum(SB)/(Sum(SB)+Sum(CS))) as 'Stolen Base %', 
      ((Sum(H)+Sum(BB))*(Sum(H)+(Sum(2B)*2)+(Sum(3B)*3)+(Sum(HR)*4)))/(Sum(AB)+Sum(BB)) as 'Runs Created'
   from 
      baseball.batting bbat 
         inner join ( Select PlayerID, 
                             min(nameFirst) as 'firstname', 
                             min(nameLast) as 'lastname', 
                             bats,
                             throws 
                         from 
                            baseball.master
                         group by 
                            playerID, 
                            nameFirst, 
                            nameLast ) bmast
            on bbat.playerID = bmast.PlayerID
         inner join ( Select PlayerID, 
                             POS
                          from baseball.fielding ) bfield
            on bbat.playerID = bfield.playerID
   where 
          yearID = '2013' 
      and AB > 60 
      and POS != 'P'
   Group by 
      bmast.playerID, 
      bmast.firstname, 
      bmast.lastname;
```

I can post my individual queries if you'd like. Please let me know!

Comment: A look at your schema, input data and output, expected and actual would be useful.

Comment: Without dumping too much too quickly, what would you like from the input and output? (its mlb data from 1940 to present, and the output filters only to 2013)

Answer (score 1):

While MySQL allows you to exclude non-aggregate fields from your `GROUP BY`, it can produce undesired results.  A starting point is including all non-aggregate fields from your `SELECT` list in your `GROUP BY`.  There may be other issues with your query as well.

Update:  This subquery is problematic, you're taking the `MIN()` of two values, but also grouping by them (this negates the `MIN()`, and you're not grouping by bats/throws.

```
 Select PlayerID, 
                             min(nameFirst) as 'firstname', 
                             min(nameLast) as 'lastname', 
                             bats,
                             throws 
                         from 
                            baseball.master
                         group by 
                            playerID, 
                            nameFirst, 
                            nameLast ) bmast
```

Comment: It worked after a fashion. It split up the results by position which at least let me see which are getting inflated total base and slugging percentage numbers

Answer (score 0):

i guess you looking for this

```
 Select 
  bbat.playerID, 
  bmast.firstname, 
  bmast.lastname, 
  bbat.yearID, 
  bbat.TeamID, 
  bmast.bats, 
  bmast.throws, 
  bfield.POS, 
  bbat.G, 
  bbat.G_batting, 
  bbat.AB, 
  bbat.R, 
  bbat.H, 
  bbat.2B, 
  bbat.3B, 
  bbat.HR, 
  bbat.RBI, 
  bbat.HBP, 
  bbat.SF, 
  ((H)+((2B)*2)+((3B)*3)+((HR)*4)) as 'TB',
  bbat.BB, 
  bbat.SO, 
  ((BB)/(SO)) as 'BB/K', 
  ((H)/(AB)) as 'Avg',
  (((H)+(BB)+(HBP))/((AB)+(BB)+(HBP)+(SF))) as 'OBP', 
  ((H)+((2B)*2)+((3B)*3)+((HR)*4))/(AB) as 'Slugging', 
  ((((H)+(BB)+(HBP))/((AB)+(BB)+(HBP)+(SF)))+(((H)+((2B)*2)+((3B)*3)+((HR)*4))/(AB))) as 'OPS',
  bbat.SB, 
  bbat.CS, 
  ((SB)/((SB)+(CS))) as 'Stolen Base %', 
  (((H)+(BB))*((H)+((2B)*2)+((3B)*3)+((HR)*4)))/((AB)+(BB)) as 'Runs Created'
 from 
 ....
```

Comment: When i get to my next class, I can try this out and see if it works. Give me a few!